# gradle Failed to apply plugin [id 'org.springframework.boot']

Tags: java, spring-boot, ubuntu, gradle

I am trying to run spring-boot project. I have some problem with gradle.

**gradle** build works fine, but I cannot run **gradlew**

Cannot run command:
`./gradlew build &&java -jar build/libs/gs-spring-boot-docker-0.1.0.jar`

Here is error:

```
Failed to apply plugin [id 'org.springframework.boot']
Spring Boot plugin requires Gradle 4.10 or later. The current version is Gradle 4.9
```

My gradle version 6.0

My gradle file

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
        }
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:2.2.4.RELEASE")
        classpath('com.google.cloud.tools.jib:com.google.cloud.tools.jib.gradle.plugin:1.8.0')
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
apply plugin: 'com.google.cloud.tools.jib'


bootJar {
    baseName = 'gs-spring-boot-docker'
    version =  '0.1.0'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
    implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    implementation('org.postgresql:postgresql')
    testCompile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
}
```

gradle build works fine, there is no error.

Comment: Is the project using gradle-wrapper? If so: could it be that the gradle-wrapper uses gradle-version 4.9?

Comment: @Turing85 I dont know how t check it. I tried `$ gradle wrapper --version`  it shows me **gradle 6**

Comment: Go in the root directory of the project, execute `./gradlew --version` (or `gradlew.bat --version` on Windows).

Answer (score 4):

The whole point of the Gradle wrapper is to have a fixed version of Gradle used in a project. This ensures that you don't by accident use an incompatible version than what the project supports. Another benefit is that it automatically downloads the correct version if you don't have it already.

When you type `gradle` (without the 'w'), you are invoking a manually downloaded distribution that you put on your path. This skips the wrapper part completely. In your case, you have apparently downloaded version 6 and updated the project to work with that version.

However, you have not updated the wrapper scripts, which is what you should have done instead. If you look in `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties`, you should see that it is set to 4.9, which is no longer compatible with your project.

To update it, you need to run the following command *twice*:

`gradlew wrapper --gradle-version 6.1.1 --distribution-type all` (assuming you want version 6.1.1, which is the latest at the time of this writing.)

The first time you run it, it will basically just change the version in `gradle-wrapper.properties` (e.g to 6.1.1). If this fails because the wrapper is too old compared to the project, just change the file manually with a text editor.

The second time you run it, Gradle will start up using that new version (e.g. 6.1.1) and, if needed, update the wrapper scripts themselves.

Also, if you like to start your Spring Boot application during development, just run `gradlew bootRun`. No need to build the jar and invoke java manually.

And also, instead of `compile`, use `implementation` in your dependencies. The former is deprecated (including `testCompile`).